# SpinningWheel prevents all events on page

Tags: jquery, iphone, jqtouch, iphone-web-app

i have integrated the SpinningWheel code from 
http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch in my 
web app. I am calling a new page where a radio group is shown and the 
spinning wheel slides up immediately as the page is called.

My radio group worked just fine before the integration of the spinning 
wheel, but now it won't work at all. Do you have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: It might be a help if you could tell us where your page is, so that we can see the code? Or, even better, if you could post a demo online and link to *that*. I'd recommend either [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/).

Comment: You can have a glance at the demo of the SpinningWheel, http://cubiq.org/dropbox/sw/. If you view it on an iPhone, you won't be able to tap anything else but the wheel and its buttons. The problem is that e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() are used, which then prevent all events on the page. How can I exclude elements from that, so their events will fire?

Answer (score 3):

try calling  `SpinningWheel.destroy();`
in the done
and close function